# Recommendations for a Basic Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion

SO,

I've been working on an animated horizontal accordion with three panels, and after trying multiple plugins, I resorted to writing my own jquery accordion using .animate, which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjnv8/33/

If you're viewing the fiddle in Chrome or FF, it should work fine, but I'm getting some odd jitter in IE. I've tried multiple tweaks but can't figure it out.

I'm considering going back to the drawing board, perhaps looking for another horizontal accordion plugin, and I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations. For some reason, horizontal accordions seem to be the unicorns of the jquery plugin world. I do have some specific requirements for a plugin:

1) I need to be able to set the accordion's height to fill the window height using jquery (I've already got the jquery to do that, you can see it in the fiddle or below)

```
var remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height()); 
$('.main').height(remaining_height);
```

2) Accordion panels must be able to hide overflow (specifically, overflow from the SVG images on each panel as in the jsfiddle).

On the other hand, if anyone does see what the problem is in IE, do let me know! I hate the idea of being set back like this by one terrible browser...

Comment: FWIW, I really like your accordion implementation.

Comment: It works great, even in IE (10) with regular images (but i guess that you already tested it)... Also, there is no jitter when svg is inserted directly to page (svg tag).. not sure if this will help... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made little different setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sjnv8/38/

```
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#panel1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

#panel2 {
  background-color: orange;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width: 100%;
  left: 33.34%;
   padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#panel3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  left: 66.66%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index:3;
}

#panel3img {
/*border-left: 1px solid #333333;
width: auto;
position: relative;
left: -35%;*/
}

.hov {
  /****keeps wide divs from flowing down to next line****/
  position: absolute;
  /****hides overflowing content****/
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*.abs {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}*/
```

All elements widths are set to width:100%, they have position:absolute, and instead of animating widths, just position is animated. For some reason -> width animation with svg images was problem for IE. Hope someone can explain, i am curious too. :)

jquery:

```
var remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height()); 
$('.main').height(remaining_height);

$('#panel1').hover(function() {
  $('#panel2').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "66.66%"}, 350),
    $('#panel3').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "83.33%"}, 350);
   // $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'66.66%'}, 350)
}, function() {
 // $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 350),
    $('#panel2').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "33.33%"}, 350),
      $('#panel3').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "66.66%"}, 350);

});

$('#panel2').hover(function() {
 // $('#panel1').stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'16.666%'}, 350),
    $('#panel3').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "83.33%"}, 350),
      $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "16.666%"}, 350);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "33.33%"}, 350),
   // $('#panel1').stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 350),
      $('#panel3').stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "66.66%"}, 350);
});

$('#panel3').hover(function() {
 // $('#panel1').stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'16.666%'}, 350),
    $('#panel2').stop(true, false, false).animate({ left: "16.666%"}, 350),
      $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "33.33%"}, 350);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "66.66%"}, 350),
   // $('#panel1').stop(true, false, false).animate({width:'33.33%'}, 350),
      $('#panel2').stop(true, false, false).animate({left: "33.33%"}, 350);
});
```